# Azure Table Storage Not saving Property

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have an abstract class that inherits from Table Entity.

```
public abstract class AzureEntityBase : TableEntity
{
    public AzureEntityBase()
    {

    }
    public virtual string TableName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    private string ObjectHash { get; set; }

    public bool IsBackedUp { get; set; }

}
```

I then have a class that implements this abstract class

```
public class DepartmentTotalEntity : AzureEntityBase
{
    public override string TableName
    {
        get
        {
            return "DepartmentTotals";
        }
    }
    public Int64 SessionDateTimeInteger { get; set; }
    public string StoreID { get { return PartitionKey; } set { PartitionKey = value; } }
    public string DetailKey { get; set; }
    public string RangeString { get; set; }
    public string DateStart { get; set; }
    public string DateEnd { get; set; }
    public Int64 DateStartInt { get; set; }
    public Int64 DateEndInt { get; set; }
    public string Dept_ID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentDescription { get; set; }                
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }        
}
```

I am submitting a revised entity to Azure table storage with the IsBackedUp value set to false.
I then have a service that runs on an Azure Compute instance that copies the row from one table storage account to another.  The other Azure table storage account is at a different Azure datacenter.  After all the rows are copied, I want to limit what I grab when I copy the next round and the IsBackedUp field is supposed to do this.

I run a function that loops the rows already inserted, checks to see if they exist at the destination, if they do exist, then update the source table row to reflect that it was backed up and write that to azure via the following code.

```
   foreach (DepartmentTotalEntity row in CopiedRows)
       {
           DepartmentTotalEntity find = dst.BrowseSingle(row.PartitionKey, row.RowKey);
           if (find != null)
           {
               row.IsBackedUp = true;
               int tmp = src.InsertOrReplace(row);
            }
       }
```

The return integer from the InsertOrReplace is the HttpStatusCode of the tableoperation and it always reads 204.  This is expected for a successful write the ATS.

For completeness here is the InsertOrReplaceRow function.

```
public int InsertOrReplace(DepartmentTotalEntity input)
        {
            if (input.PartitionKey.IsNull())
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("PartitionKey");
            }
            if (input.RowKey.IsNull())
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("RowKey");
            }

            TableOperation replaceOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(input);
            TableResult result = table.Execute(replaceOperation);
            return result.HttpStatusCode;
        }
```

The main problem is that the IsBackedUp field is not being updated when the InsertOrReplace command is being called in the third block of code.

Banging me head against a wall here trying to figure out why ATS will not accept my revision.

I can successfully change the value of IsBackedUp using Azure Table Storage Explorer.  I have confirmed that the datatype of the column is Boolean.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if I have posted enough of the code to be of assistance.  The only class that is not posted is the rest of the class that surrounds the last code block. It is over 2000 lines so I omitted it for brevity.  That class has the CloudTable, CloudTableClient and CloudStorageAccount variables.

Comment: Do you get a new row? Or just no sign of anything edited. The RowKey and PartitionKey is definitely the same for the row you are updating? Otherwise you're insertorUpdate will be an insert (not an update).

Comment: @Stuart  - No new row.  The RowKey and PartitionKey are most certainly the same.  The effect is just no sign of anything being edited.  That is why I find this strange because the Storage Explorer edits the field without issues and I get a success code response from ATS as well.

Comment: Does it work if you use TableBatchOperation rather than TableOperation (but your batch will be just one item) ?

Comment: I did not try that.  I will see what I can do about giving that a try.  It is an excellent suggestion, btw so thank you, regardless of whether or not it works.  The reason it is difficult to try is that I moved on and solved the problem another way.